# python nested dict gets Key error when using += operand

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a large CSV file where each row is a sales event distinguished by rep ID, month, and value of the sale.  I want to build a cumulative sales volume for each rep by month.  So the result would look like:

```
repID  Jan  Feb  Mar  ...
aaa    2    5    8  ... 
...
...
...
```

I am using a nested Dict and getting a KeyError: 2

Here is my code:

```
Outerdict = {}

for row in readfile:
    nesteddict = {}
    if repID not in Outerdict:
         nesteddict[month] = sales
         Outerdict[repID] = nesteddict  
    else:
         Outerdict[repID][month] += sales
```

the key error is pointing to the last line of code.  Not sure if it has something to do with the += operand?

Comment: What is `repID` variable and `month` variable? ?

Comment: can you show the csv file content??

Comment: 'KeyError' is due to  dictionary not having key. Either your 'repID' or 'month' variable has value that is not populated in dictionary

Comment: If you replace everything in the middle with `Outerdict.setdefault(repID, {}).setdefault(month, 0)` your last line will work.

Comment: You seem to have tried to simplify your code to post it, but in the process, you changed it so much you took out the original bug and replaced it with a bunch of different ones. This code will just `NameError`, and if `readfile`, `repID`, `month`, and `sales` are defined, it won't `KeyError`.

Answer (score 1):

`repID` exists doesn't mean that `month` exists too.

```
Outerdict = {}

for row in readfile:
    repID = row['repID']
    month = row['month']
    if repID not in Outerdict:
        Outerdict[repID] = {}
    if month not in Outerdict[repID]: # This month may hasn't existed before
        Outerdict[repID][month] = sales
    else:
        Outerdict[repID][month] += sales
```

Comment: `if repID not in Outerdict.keys()` - **no no no no no!** The `keys` call is utterly superfluous, and on Python 2, it will create a list of keys and search through them one by one to find `repID` rather than using a quick hash lookup. Same problem with the other `keys` call. It is almost never a good idea to use `dict.keys()`.